# Retrieving the catalog of a music service

Tags: sonos

My app is integrated with the Sonos speakers and I'd like to provide the user the ability to select the container of the music service provider - i.e. playlist/stations/...leafs of the tree (e.g. Amazon Music, Spotify, ...).

I managed to understand the vast majority of the SOAP calls however, I could not figure out how to query the user's selected service (devicelink) and provide the same list that the Sonos controller show.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sonos App does not provide a access other/third party music services via the Sonos API's unless you already have an integration with these services via their public APIs.